# Batch commands in linux, gnome, bash

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I am trying to make batch commands (sh) on linux for start, stop and restart my web server lighttpd, with partial success.
Ideally, I would like to doubleclick icon and nothing more to do a job.

Now, on doubleclick appear dialog "Do you want to run "START.sh", or display its contents?" and "START.sh" is an executable text file." with Run in terminal, Display, Cancel and Run buttons. Run in terminal do a job after typing password.
My script look as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo /bin/bash /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
echo
echo -n "   [ENTER] to continue... "
read var_keypress
```

Is here any way for my script to run without prompted dialog and that I don't need to type password every time?

Comment: Is `sudo service lighttpd start|stop|restart` that hard?

Comment: A batch script is something to work on many files. this is a starter script and should be migrate to superuser.

Comment: another option may be to use `gksu`

Comment: It is not that hard. Just to explore possibilities. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure sudo to be usable with no password as described here:

http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/06/22/configure-sudo-nopasswd/

Be sure to let sudo only run specific commands without password, not all.

Comment: I try this but also with partial success. I can't disable password for specific command but for all sudo for user. I think this is ok. I am only user of my comp.

Comment: Actually, now my batch don't ask for password but ask "Run in terminal", "Display", "Cancel", "Run" what is also unwanted. Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: Should be a gnome-related issue... can you create a link (in gnome, not a symlink) to a program?

Comment: Yes I can. Link acts at same way. Where to look to fix this?

Comment: In KDE, i can create a link to a Program, call sh or bash with the script as an argument, try to do the same in gnome ;-)

Comment: If I type in terminal /home/name/my_lighttpd/RESTART.sh this works ok. But if I start RESTART.sh or link to them with doubleclick then dialog appear. But OK, I can live with that :) Btw. I use Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid that with a system init script (`ln -s /etc/init.d/lighttpd /etc/rc2.d/S99lighttpd` on Debian) or with a [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) entry for `@reboot`

Comment: For RH/Fedora/CentOS, `chkconfig --level 2345 lighttpd on`.  Assuming the init script has a proper chkconfig header and has been set up via something like `chkconfig --add lighttpd`.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I didn't anything useful with this. Isn't this same as "create link" from nautilus?

Comment: probably yes, but I know much more commands (which are *standardized* by Posix) than graphical interfaces (which are difficult to explain in forums). I suggest you to learn basic commands.